# How to send message to specific user from specific user with slack in dot net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I had tried to send message as bot user in slack using the chat.postmessage method and put user id at the place of channel. I want to send any user from specific user id in slack team user.

Comment: The description of your problem is very broad.  Please include some of the code you have tried and any error messages you may have received.  This will help you to get an answer.  Also please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Slack bot, you have to use [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#sending_messages) from Slack API. You have just to send web request with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data, for example something like this:

```
string exampleJson = " { \"text\": \"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one.\" }";

var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("YOUR-SLACK-WEBHOOK-URL"));
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";

Byte[] bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(exampleJson);

Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();

new StreamReader(http.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```